# OpenAPI, Swagger. Cписок из словарей с словарями

Tags: python, json, flask, yaml, openapi

Всем привет. Пытаюсь описать входной json для моего приложения на connexion (Python).
Формат входного json такой:

```
{
    "Id":"123",
    "Calc":"321",
    "Ways":[{"Id":"1", "Orig":{"long":51.1563, "lat":55.5311}, "Dest":{"long":21.1233, "lat":52.5111}}, {"Id":"2", "Orig":{"long":23.1134, "lat":23.5871}, "Dest":{"long":51.1563, "lat":55.5311}}],
    "Creation":"2019-03-11T13:17:01.222178Z",
    "Email":"pomogite@mne.pzhlst"
}
```

Вопрос прикован конкретно к полю parameters, в частности к полю Ways и звучит так:
Мне собирать **yaml** файл матрешкой, тобишь до полного исчерпания описания полей?

На данный момент выглядит он так, get запрост, но это неверное решение.
Фрагмент swagger ->

```
get:
    operationId: TrashDist.solve
    description: Auto generated using Swagger Inspector
    parameters:
            - name: Id
              in: query 
              schema:
                type: string
                
            - name: Calc
              in: query 
              schema:
                type: string
                
            - name: Ways
              in: query 
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    Id:
                      type: string
                    Orig:
                      type: object
                      propreties:
                        long:
                          type: number
                        lat:
                          type: number                        
                    Dest:
                      type: object
                      propreties:
                        long:
                          type: number
                        lat:
                          type: number
        
            - name: Creation
              in: query 
              schema:
                type: string
                
            - name: Email
              in: query 
              schema:
                type: string
```

Когда я делаю таким образом, на приеме данных, приложение выдает ошибку: 'id' is not of type 'object'...

Comment: Хотя бы хочешься убедиться что передается вся структура.
Написал весьма смешной костыль, просто в запрос поместил строку запроса json. Строку передал как значение по ключу json:


data = { "json" : " ... " }

передав в функцию исполнения на сервере обработал и считал ее как json формат и вернул обратно json таким же образом...
Это вариант для случая когда совсем уж тяжко и срочно нужна реализация.

Вопрос по форме заданный выше остается открытым

Comment: я не заметил вопрос. разобрался?

Comment: вообще такой запрос обычно посылается post-ом и описывается, соответственное, в body

Comment: @nörbörnën , я пробовал и через post запрос. Проблема в том что походу у сваггера не получается считать с глубокой вложенностью схему. я искал по запросу nested dict, json что бы брал тоже пробовал. но не получается. Он просто ловит входной json на первом его ключе в поле Ways, котоый получается между прочим object, и ругается что первое значение подано string))) на этом моменте я сложил полномочия и просто передал весь json прост окак строку с ключом 'json' ))) костыль